# Need to use collections to sort colors by name and be hex value

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to write a program that reads from an input file and pairs colors by their hex value.  For example: Black 000000 would be one pair.  Here is what I have so far:

```
public class HexColors{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList <String> colorsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner hexColors = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

    while (hexColors.hasNext()) {
        colorsArray.add(hexColors.nextLine());
    }

// Assuming I have to use a map to accomplish this.
    Map<String, String> hexMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 


    System.out.println("Test" + hexMap);

    System.out.print("The colors entered were:\n" );
    for (Iterator<String> itr = colorsArray.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
        System.out.print(itr.next() + "\n");
    Collections.sort(colorsArray);
    System.out.println("The colors sorted by name are:");
    for(String colorsSorted : colorsArray){
        System.out.println(colorsSorted);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I have it displaying by the color's natural order, and by using collections.sort, I also have them displaying in alphabetical order.  Important note here: I'm not looking for a full solution, just some pointers on where I should go next.  Is it possible to store my input from input.txt as a Map? Or should I be converting the ArrayList into a map somehow? Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you give a few lines of the input.txt so we can see what format it's in?

Comment: @PaulStatham Here are two of the colors: Purple 990099
Orange FF6600

Comment: Is it one color pair per line or can one line contain multiple pairs?

Comment: @vanje one color pair per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file contains one color pair per line, it is easier to read the file line by line with a `BufferedReader` (see [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)) and then split each line to extract the color name and the hex value.

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  // Split line
  // Add color name and hex value to your data structure
}
```

There are many ways to split such a line. E.g. you can use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).
Or you can search for the space character position via [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and then extract the parts with [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

For your datamodel there are many alternatives, too. A `HashMap` may be a good idea, because you always have the colornames which maps to the hex value. Are you sure, that each color name is unique in your file?

But using only a `HashMap` you will lost the original order. A more suitable data structure would be a `LinkedHashMap` which internally uses a doubly linked list to preserve insertion order.

So with a `LinkedHashMap` you are finished with your first use case (original order). Iterate over the `LinkedHashMap` and your are done.

The best way to iterate over a `Map` is to use the [entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29):

```
for(Entry<String, String> colorPair : map.entrySet()) {
  String colorName = colorPair.getKey();
  String colorHex = colorPair.getValue();
  // Process colorName and colorHex ...
}
```

For alphabetical order you can get all entries of the map's [keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) and put them into a `ArrayList` and use `Collections.sort()`. Then iterate over the `ArrayList` and retrieve the hex value via the map. Sounds a little bit complicated. But it's feasible.

But the difficult part comes with the natural color order (you mean sort by hex value, right?). So you can get all color hex values via [Map.values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29), sort them and ...

You cannot use the map the other way around. Here you want to retrieve the color name by the hex value, but the color names are the map's keys. I assume you don't want to use third party libraries and there is no bidirectional map in Java's standard library.

Of course you can use a second reverted map, but maybe we should reconsider the choice at the beginning to use a map as the data model.

A simpler way would be to create your own `ColorPair` class and then use a simple `ArrayList` to hold all your color pairs. After inserting all color pairs the list has the original order. Then you can use `Collections.sort()` to order by color name and then by color hex value.

This would be a simple `ColorPair` implementation:

```
class ColorPair {
  private String name;
  private String hex;

  public ColorPair(String name, String hex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hex = hex;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getHex() {
    return hex;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("[ColorPair name=%s, hex=%s]", name, hex);
  }
}
```

You could implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface here and define a default order for your `ColorPair` instances. But you want two different orders so you have to use the Comparator class for `Collections.sort()` anyway. (You can try it as an exercise.)

So assuming you have a method `parseColorPair()` which takes one line of your input file and returns a `ColorPair` instance you can read your file like so:

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
String line;
List<ColorPair> colorPairs = new ArrayList<ColorPair>();
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  colorPairs.add(parseColorPair(line));
}

// Output in original order
for(ColorPair colorPair: colorPairs) {
  System.out.println(colorPair); // using our custom ColorPair.toString() method
}
```

To sort your list by color name you have to implement the interface `Comparator<ColorPair>`.

```
Collections.sort(colorPairs, new Comparator<ColorPair>() {
  public int compare(ColorPair colorPair1, ColorPair colorPair2) {
    // Compare the names of colorPair1 and colorPair2 and return
    // a negative value, if colorPair1.getName() is lesser than colorPair2's name.
    // return a positive value (greater than 0) if the first name is greater than
    // the second name and return 0 if the names are equal.
    // Hint: Look for String.compare()
  }
});
```

You cannot use the `Collections.sort()` version without a `Comparator` here because your `ColorPair` class doesn't implement the `Comparable<ColorPair>` interface.

Sorting by hex value is similar. The `Comparator` implementation differs only by comparing the hex values instead of names.

So using the right data structure makes the implementation of the use cases straight forward, but it is not trivial to find the right data structure for a given problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  Explained it way better than I could have ever hoped.